# Replace a client library with a mock from a test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

Is there a way to replace a client library (which communicates with a remote server) with a mock object from within a unittest?

Here's a diagram to explain what I'm attempting to do

```
    +---------------+
    |     tests     |----{ mock }
    +---------------+       |
            |               |
            v               |
    +---------------+       |
    |     model     |       |
    +---------------+       |
            |               |
            v               |
    +---------------+       |
    | client-module |<--{replaces}
    +---------------+
            ^
            :
            :
            v
    +---------------+
    |    service    |
    +---------------+
```

Since the tests import the model, which imports the client-module, there doesn't seem to be a way to apply the mock to the model's internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If model.py does an

```
import client_module
```

and doesn't use any features of it at import time, you can do

```
import model

...

model.client_module = MyMockModule()
```

where `MyMockModule` returns suitable mocks for stuff the real `client_module` provides. I haven't shown setUp/tearDown stuff to take care of this, but hopefully you get the idea,

If `model` *does* use stuff from `client_module` at import time, you'll need to replace `sys.modules['client_module']` with the mocked module before importing `model`.